# Mock a REST request of a child service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I try to test a `@RestController` within a integration test suite using `MockMvc`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class WebControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getStatusReurnsSomething() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/status")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

The `@RestController` (`WebController`) calls an injected `@Service` (`RestClientService`) which uses `RestTemplate` to call another REST server. This leads to the following error when running the test.

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "http://test123.com/42/status": test123.com; nested
>   exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: test123.com

I used `MockRestServiceServer` for the integration test of the `@Service` itself but have no idea how to archieve this within the test of `@RestController`.

How can I simulate a correct REST call of the `RestTemplate`?

---

The `@RestController` class.

```
@RestController
public class WebController {
    private final RestClientService service;

    @Autowired
    public WebController(RestClientService service) {this.service = service;}

    @GetMapping("/status")
    public String getStatus() {
        // extract pid from database ...
        int pid = 42;

        return this.service.getStatus(42);
    }
}
```

The `@Service`class.

```
@Service
public class RestClientService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public RestClientService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {this.restTemplate = restTemplate;}

    public String getStatus(int pid) {
        String url = String.format("http://test123.com/%d/status", pid);
        return this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: it complains that it couldnt find the host test123.com . did you test that REST Service with any client tool, like postman ? if yes, was it successful ?

Comment: Just a minor comment - it is a very bad practice to hardcode something like rest URL in the method like you did inside `getStatus()`

Comment: @Arun The question is not about test123.com. It's just an example.It's about mocking the  test123.com REST service.

Answer (score 2):

Integration/Unit testing doesn't work that way.Objective of this kind of testing is to run through your code and make sure all the business requirement are met but not to hit other system or DB.Here in your case u shouldn't be hitting test123.com to get back data.What needs to done here is that you should mock that method.

```
public String getStatus(int pid) {
    String url = String.format("http://test123.com/%d/status", pid);
    return this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
}
```

So that control doesn't enter this method but return you back the mock data(Dummy data).

For example let say that there are 2 kind of status this method is returning  and you need to do some business validation based on the string returned.In this case u need to write 2 integration test and make sure the mocking method returns 2 different value(Dummy value instead of hitting that end point)

Reason why we are writing unit testing/integration testing is to make sure your entire code is working  as expected but not to hit other system  from ur code.

Comment: Thanks. I totally agree. Maybe my question is misleading. I don't want to call the the external REST service. But I have no idea how to manipulate the injected `RestTemplate`. Mocking `getStatus` would be my second choice.

Comment: U need to create restTemplate mock object..That will help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only test your controller layer, you would do like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MockServletContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class WebControllerIT {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private RestClientService service

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        service = new RestClientService(restTemplate);
        WebController webController = new WebController(service);
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(webController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getStatusReurnsSomething() throws Exception {
      //Mock the behaviour of restTemplate.
      doReturn("someString").when(restTemplate).getForObject(anyString(), anyString());
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/status")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```